# Confused on const correctness with static array of pointers to const objects

Tags: c, objective-c, static, constants, const-correctness

I'm still not sure I *totally* get how this particular case should work out.  So if I want to declare an array of NSStrings that won't change, is this correct?

```
static NSString * const strings[] = {@"String 1", @"String 2", ...};
```

Is the `static` necessary? (what does it do?)  Am I missing an extra `const` somewhere?  There's just too many places for it to go!  Gah!  Am I doing it wrong, or am I just paranoid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have:

```
static NSString * const strings[] = {@"String 1", @"String 2", ...};
```

Is an array of immutable pointers.

You might want:

```
static NSString const *strings[] = {@"String 1", @"String 2", ...};
```

An array of pointers to immutable `NSString` objects.

Or

```
static NSString const * const strings[] = {@"String 1", @"String 2", ...};
```

An array of immutable pointers to immutable `NSString` objects.

The ["Clockwise-Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) is the technique I use to interpret C declarations.

The `static` keyword means that the array's 'storage duration' is for the entire life of the program. If the declaration is in a function, then the array doesn't go away when the function returns (though the scope will still be only for that function).  If the declaration is at file scope, the `static` keyword will make the name of the array visible only within that compilation unit (ie., source file).  Another source file could not access the array through an `extern` declaration.

Comment: Perhaps better worded as "An immutable array of pointers", "An array of immutable pointers", "An array of pointers to immutable objects", or whichever fits best.

Comment: Since NSStrings are immutable objects, do I actually need the extra const?

Answer (score 1):

You read C declarations from the inside out, first moving right to highly bound operators like [] and then moving left. So, you have: strings, an array, of constant, pointers, to NSString, that is static.

That's perfectly reasonable but not what you said you wanted.

To create pointers to constant strings you will need the `const` on the other side of the `*`, so you will have strings, an array, of pointers, to constant, NSString, which are static.

You can put `const` in both places, if you want.

Using `static` storage class is a bit like defining a class variable. It is the same as `static` in C99, a module-level lexical scope.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have class variables.  We can get the same effect as a class variable with static storage defined in the .m file, but please don't gloss over the difference.